# How to show (in a hand waving manner) that the Godel sentence is true

Tags: logic, proof, goedel

I have been reading Graham Priest's *The Logic of Paradox*, and there is a section where he tried to show that our informal proof argument (in Priest's terminology, naive proof procedure) is more powerful in terms of proving power than our formal proof systems, by showing that the Godel sentence can be **shown** to be true if we go through the formal theory's meta-language. (Attached below)

I think I understand how he is proceeding from (1) all the way to (4). What I don't understand is what is his assumption/beginning of the argument, and how he is getting his conclusion?

If we take (1) to be true, then indeed from there we seem to be able to show that the Godel sentence is true. But where is (1) coming from?

(1) seems to be saying that **IF** there is a proof of the Godel sentence, then it (as denoted by its Godel code) is true; which I suppose is a fair point. (But is that already enough to warrant this conditional?) Then (2) to (4) seem to be equivalences of the conclusion, these are also relatively straight forward.

But surely until we actually have a code for the proof of the Godel sentence (which would then satisfies the antecedent and thus allows us to isolate the conclusion, ie. ¬∃x Prov(xg)), what we have remains a conditional. So I am not entirely sure how he has seemingly applied Modus Ponens to get ¬∃x Prov(xg) at the end?

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: For a good overview, see B.Buldt, [The Scope of Gödel’s First Incompleteness Theorem (2014)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11787-014-0107-3).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, I have been reading Peter Smith's An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems so I roughly know how Godel proves the Incompleteness; but I am afraid I don't see how Godel's proof comes into play here. Isn't what Priest is doing here independent of Godel's proof? It just seems like he is applying Modus Ponens to (1) somehow to get the conclusion

Comment: What you quoted is very misleading or meaningless. There is no such thing as "P's meta-language", unless it simply means "P+Con(P)". The author fails to state this clearly, and so is either ignorant or trying to cover it up. All this has nothing to do with "semantics". Any reasonable foundational system for mathematics **can formulate and reason about its own semantics**. What it cannot do is to prove itself consistent. Neither can so-called 'naive semantic reasoning' get anywhere; as I said the extra assumption is "Con(P)", not any 'semantic' thing.

Comment: Since you said you have gone through Peter Smith's book, I assumed you fully understood all the technical details, in which case it should be trivial for you to verify what I said. If you are unsure about the exact details of Godel coding, you can take a look at a [self-contained computability-based proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2486348/21820) that is more general and may help you to grasp what exactly are the critical conditions for the incompleteness phenomenon to arise.

Comment: @user21820 'Any reasonable foundational system for mathematics can formulate and reason about its own semantics.' I could very well be wrong, but doesn't a theory need a truth/satisfaction predicate to be able to formulate its own semantics? As far as I understand, PA does not have that.

Comment: @DanielMak: I'll give you frank feedback here. You are very confused, not wrong. There is no such thing as a "truth/satisfaction predicate"... It seems to me that you don't even have the basic background in FOL needed to understand Peter Smith's book. **Truth** is only well-defined **relative** to some structure, and you can find the definition of FOL semantics in any standard introductory textbook on mathematical logic. Any reasonable foundational system supports such definition, as well as the proof that a FOL theory S is consistent iff Con(S) is true **in the naturals**.

Comment: I also don't know why you bring up PA. PA is not a reasonable foundation for mathematics, but that is irrelevant to what I said. Most logicians would agree that a reasonable foundation should be at least as strong as ACA. Anyway, before we continue it is best that you tell me how much background in logic you have. Can you write formal proofs in a deductive system for FOL? Can you prove the completeness and compactness theorems for FOL?

Comment: @user21820 I was referring to what this Wiki is discussing; and yes I can do both of those.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_predicate

Comment: @DanielMak: I know what that wikipedia article is talking about, but as I said already there is **no such thing** in any reasonable foundational system. This is a trivial fact (also known as Tarski's undefinability theorem). By the way the wikipedia article is of poor quality; we do not need anything near ZF set theory (transfinite recursion up to ω[1] suffices). Since you are familiar with FOL, you should know what I said: Truth is only well-defined relative to some structure, and the definition of "truth" as part of FOL semantics has **nothing to do with** a (Tarski) truth-predicate.

Comment: I suggest you carefully go over the FOL semantics again. A trivial recursion suffices to define "⊨" as a relation between FOL structures and sentences over them. Since any reasonable foundational system is an FOL theory (or equivalent to one), it can very well reason about its own semantics, as well as about models of itself, exactly as I stated in my initial comments.

Comment: To be clear, transfinite recursion up to ω[1] is for constructing an extension of an FOL theory that has its own truth-predicate, but such an extension is never a reasonable foundational system. And such transfinite recursion is not at all needed for a foundational system to be able to reason about its own semantics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) is a result about **formal systems**.

Its proof requires certain assumptions about the properties of specific formal system **F**: basically, about its ["expressive capabilities"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#Rep).

In a sense that can be specified rigorously, system **F** must have the capabilities to manufacture the [*provability predicate*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#AriForLan) for **F**, i.e. a suitable formula **PrF(x)** such that :

> **F ⊢ A** iff **PrF("A")** is a true sentence about the natural numbers,

where **"A"** is the Gödel-number for formula **A**.

The second key feature of system **F** is the so-called [*Diagonalization Lemma*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#DiaSelRef) that can be applied to formula **¬PrF(x)**, to get :

> **F ⊢ G ↔ ¬ PrF("G")** [here **PrF("G")** is the same as **∃x Prov(x,"G")** of Priest].

The third key assumption is *consistency* of **F**; but G's proof can be simplified assuming the slightly stronger condition of *soundness*.

Now for the main result: assume that **F** proves **G**, i.e. assume **F ⊢ G**.

Due to the property of the *provability predicate*, the assumption about the provability of **G** amounts to the fact that sentence **PrF("G")** is true.

Using the diagonal equivalence, we have that **G** is false.

Then by the assumption that **F** is sound (it proves only true sentences about the natural numbers), it follows that **F ⊬ G**, which contradicts our assumption that **F** proves **G**.

So by propositional logic:

> (i) **F ⊬ G**.

Thus, by the property of the provability predicate, we have that **¬ PrF("G")** is true.

So by the diagonal equivalence:

> (ii) **G** is true.

Then **¬ G** is false and thus, by soundness of **F**:

> (iii) **F ⊬ ¬G**.

In conclusion:

> > if **F** is sound, then **F ⊬ G**, **G** is true, and **F ⊬ ¬G**.

---

Having said that, what is Priest's handwaving argument ?

The starting point is the "purely syntactical" proof that **G** is not provable in **F**, i.e. **F ⊬ G** [this is result (i) above].

By the property of provability predicate:

> **F ⊢ A** iff **PrF("A")** is a true sentence about the natural numbers,

we have that **¬  PrF("A")** is a true sentence, i.e. **¬ ∃x Prov(x,"G")** is a true sentence [this is result (ii) above].

Comment: Oh I see now; I thought Priest was doing something different from Godel but in reality he was just sketching out Godel's proof. Thank you so much that is very clear!

Answer (score 4):

(1) is a special case of the general principle that if you accept a statement, then you accept that the statement is true.  If you believe snow is white, then you believe "Snow is white" is true.  It remains handwavy until you give a precise explanation of what you mean by "X is true."  And that turns out to be a tricky business.

Comment: Ah ok, so (1) is an instance of Tarski's T-schema? But how do we get ¬∃x Prov(xg)? Priest seems to have done a Modus Ponens on the T-schema to get it, but I don't see how he can

Comment: The sentence g is gotten by diagonalization, so that it says "there does not exist a proof of g."